# App Domain -Running Tests in Parallel (MS Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, selenium, bdd, specflow

I would like to run my test cases in parallel, using specflow+ in C#. I came across Memory Isolation(App Domain).

Any ideas on implementing this are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this blog post about configuring the parallel execution: https://the-engineers.net/2016/04/08/using-specflowrunners-parallelization-features/

As long as you have no problems with your shared resources, you do not need to implement anything to run the tests in parallel.

Full disclosure: I am one of the developers of SpecFlow+.

Comment: Exactly! That's the page where I landed up and solved the problem using srProfile. I wonder is there any way to reduce the "Stop After Failures" ?! Even when I zeroed down, it kept running the failed test cases thrice! <Execution stopAfterFailures="0" testThreadCount="5" testSchedulingMode="Sequential" />

Comment: See http://www.specflow.org/plus/documentation/SpecFlowPlus-Runner-Profiles/#Execution
You have to set retryFor to None. So failing ones are not restarted.

Comment: Got it up and running! I thought i'd ask you about Selenium Grid running in parallel with specrun. I tried changing the ~.srprofile~ and app.config file. But ending up with attribute errors. Any ideas on Running Selenium grid with specrun is highly appreciated

Comment: @cashanzlo is this a new question? If yes, please make a new question here or post it here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/specrun